# jQuery multiple animations and tracking of their progress

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm writing a script with many animations that occur in parallel and in different orders. A specific set of animations is used depending on what is clicked on the web page. The functions are reused and do not come in the same order every time.

The issue comes when the user clicks another element without letting the first set of animation to complete. In this type of instance the script breaks and fails to function as intended. This is obviously because the progression wasn't completed and another set of animations began to be executed.

My question is if there is any practice in identifying whether animations are currently being run in order to prevent another set of animation from being executed before the current set is complete.

Comment: Use [`:animated`](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/)

Comment: There is a :animated selector you can use to select all elements that are currently being animated. If you end up with more than 0 elements in that collection, then you know something is being animated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [:animated](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) selector:

```
if ($("yourSelector:animated").length > 0) {
    // Some of the elements matching 'yourSelector' are still being animated.
}
```

Alternately, you can call [finish()](http://api.jquery.com/finish/) before starting a new animation to force the current one to complete immediately:

```
$("yourElement").finish().animate({
    // The properties to animate...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make sure the animations associated with a particular element complete normally before starting a new animation, you can use the `.queue()` function. [See my example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/VtzSw/3/).

```
$( function() {
    $(".clicker").on("click", function() {
        var self = $(this);
        self.queue( function(next) {
            self.animate({left:"+=100"}, 1000); // Replace with your animation
            next();
        });
    });
});
```

[Read more about the queue function on api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/queue/).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery also has a hidden exposed variable called `$.timers` which contains the Array of all things currently animated/etc. Which speed-wise is incredibly fast, performance-wise you wouldn't want to be looping through `$('*').is(':animated')`, to test if anything on the page is moving.

I've created a little function that loops through an interval over and over until they are all finished, and then executes a callback function.

```
function isPageAnimated (_func) {    
    var testAnimationInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if ($.timers.length === 0) { // any page animations finished
            clearInterval(testAnimationInterval);
            _func(); // callback function
        }
    }, 100);
}
```